# Prestashop, How to Edit One Order Reference

Tags: reference, prestashop

My shop is built with Prestashop 1.5.6.

In Control panel > Orders > Orders :
I can select an order and amend a few things related to this order (such as adding or deleting one product).

But, **there is no way of editing the order Reference**.

**How would it be possible to edit one order Reference** ?

I found modules which are able to modify the rule used to create the order Reference.
But my goal is not to modify such rule.

I would like to have the possibility of **changing the order reference just for some orders, one by one**.

I thank you in advance for any suggestion.

Patrick

Answer (score 1):

The order reference is a significant and unique token of an order. When the order was composed and saved it can't be changed. Customer gets an email with this order reference. But if you insist on changing it - you need to get a developer help to code a custom Prestashop module for your needs or manually interfere a database (not recommended).

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it from backoffice without custom development. If you want to manually edit in database, reference is stored at table

```
PS_PREFIX_orders
```